# ManyToMany left join query builder

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

I have entity A with ManyToMany doctrine relation wite entity B

I want to get data of the entity A using query builder in this way

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'entity_A_field_1' => 'entity_A_field_1_value',
        'entity_A_field_2' => 'entity_A_field_2_value',
        'entity_A_field_3' => 'entity_A_field_3_value',
        'entity_B' => array(
            0 => array(
                'entity_B_field_1' => 'entity_B_field_1_value',
                'entity_B_field_2' => 'entity_B_field_2_value',
                'entity_B_field_3' => 'entity_B_field_3_value',
            ),
            2 => array(
                'entity_B_field_1' => 'entity_B_field_1_value',
                'entity_B_field_2' => 'entity_B_field_2_value',
                'entity_B_field_3' => 'entity_B_field_3_value',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        'entity_A_field_1' => 'entity_A_field_1_value',
        'entity_A_field_2' => 'entity_A_field_2_value',
        'entity_A_field_3' => 'entity_A_field_3_value',
        'entity_B' => null
    ),
);
```

her is my entities: entity A is product

```
class Product
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="store_product_category"
     * )
     */
    private $categories;
```

Entity B is category

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $products;
```

I want to get all my products with their categories using query builder and without conditions (if they have| null if they don't). i need to get them all.

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'product_id'        => 'product_id_value',
        'product_name'      => 'product_name_value',
        'product_reference' => 'product_reference_value',
        'categories'        => array(
            0 => array(
                'category_id'    => 'category_id_value',
                'category_name'  => 'category_name_value',
                'category_token' => 'category_token_value',
            ),
            2 => array(
                'category_id'    => 'category_id_value',
                'category_name'  => 'category_name_value',
                'category_token' => 'category_token_value',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        'product_id'        => 'product_id_value',
        'product_name'      => 'product_name_value',
        'product_reference' => 'product_reference_value',
        'category'          => null
    ),
);
```

Comment: Please share code (and correct typo). We can't use what you provided. What is A? What is B? Which is the owning side? You want to get data from A, but from which source? From URL parameter? From B? Also, there are quite a lot of DQL examples on SO. You can check my answers from my profile, I provided a lot of DQL answer here and there.

Comment: Sorry i wrote this issue using my phone that's why i didn't share code.

Comment: so you probably should share code as soon as you can ^^

Comment: If I were you I'd just create some sort of ProductModel which would do this for you instead of trying to create complex QueryBuilder. It would be pretty easy to get the data model you desire with just a simple foreach loop over all products